# HTML input event called twice

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with html/javascript code, the code should format numbers taken from keyboard (1 -> 0.01, 2-> 0.12, 3->1.23 ... 6->1,234.56).

It seems that the result of substring and substr is appended twice. In debug it works fine but without debug it doesn't. (1 -> 0.011, 2->1.122, 3->112.233)
It works the same for delete or backspace.

Here is the code:

```js
formatElementAmount = function(f, d) {
  d = d.replace(/\./g, '');
  d = d.replace(/\,/g, '');
  d = parseFloat(d);
  d = d + '';
  var c = document.getElementById((f.target || f.srcElement).id);
  var b = '0123456789';
  var a = f.which || f.keyCode;
  if (a == 13) { // keycode 13 = enter >
    return false;
  }
  if (a == 9) { // keycode 9 == tab
    return true;
  }
  if (a == 8 || a == 46) { // keyCode 8 == backspace, 46 == delete
    if (d.length > 0) {
      d = d.substring(0, d.length - 1);
      c.value = '';
    }
    c.value = format(d);
    return false;
  }
  if (c.value.length > 12) {
    c.value = '';
    c.value = format(d);
    return false;
  }
  if (a >= 96 && a <= 105) { // 96 = numbpad 0, 105 = numpad 9
    a = a - 48;
  }
  key = String.fromCharCode(a);
  if (b.indexOf(key) == -1) {
    return false;
  }
  if ((d.length == 0) && (key == '0')) {} else {
    d = d + key;
  }
  c.value = '';
  c.value = format(d);
  return false;
};

format = function(f) {
  if (f.length == 0) {
    return '0.00';
  }
  if (f.length == 1) {
    return '0.0' + f;
  }
  if (f.length == 2) {
    return '0.' + f;
  }

  var a, b, c, d, e;

  if (f.length > 2) {
    a = '';
    for (c = 0, d = f.length - 3; d >= 0; d--) {
      if (c == 3) {
        a += ',';
        c = 0;
      }
      a += f.charAt(d);
      c++;
    }
    b = '';
    len2 = a.length;
    for (d = len2 - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
      b += a.charAt(d);
    }
    e = f.substr(f.length - 2);
    b += '.' + e;
  }
  return b;
};
```

```html
<input id="paymentForm" name="paymentForm" type="text" value="0.00" onkeydown="if(this.value =='') this.value ='0.00';
                            if (!formatElementAmount(event, this.value)) {
                                event.stopPropagation();
                            }"></input>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all your should stop using `event.stopPropagation()` - it doesn't stop default event. Also don't use `event.preventDefault()` which is not recommended. Instead use `return false` which disable default event effect and stop insert chars from keyboard. 
Also use `keypress` event instead of `keydown` (I can't explain why it works because I don't know).

```
<input id="paymentForm" name="paymentForm" type="text" value="0.00" onkeypress="if(this.value =='') this.value ='0.00';
                            if (!formatElementAmount(event, this.value)) {
                                return false;
                            }"></input>
```

I tested this fix in Firefox, IE10 & Edge which i actually have on my computer.

Comment: "not recommended" by whom?

Comment: @JohnKeyes i don't remember where I read this. When you use stopPropagation(), you are blocking only default event but bubbling is still allowed - this could be some tricky for begginers and could make some problems when someone don't know how events works.

Comment: What is "not recommended" by standards is the use of the inline events attribute. You should keep your scripts out of the markup. And if you follow the recommended way of attaching an event (`addEventListener()`), `return false` won't stop anything else than the callback

Comment: @Kaiido good point but the question is not connected with code quality. I fixed code from question and it should works.

Comment: @kodipe, but your statement that `preventDefault` should not be used is completely wrong and dangerous in some extents (*I may be overtaking it sorry ;-P*)

Comment: @Kaiido ok, maybe my "not recommended" was too general :) But in comment I explained this opinion. I added link to it in answer for clarity.

Comment: @kodipe that only concerns `stopPropagation()`. `preventDefault()` is the way to prevent the default behavior of an event.

Comment: @Kaiido I thought about preventDefault() when I wrote this comment. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is it doesn't prevent the default action of the `keyDown` event:

```
if (!formatElementAmount(event, this.value)) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: thanks, your version works, I didn't knew about default action of event, I'm a beginner and I will read more about it

Comment: @daniel.deliu you can study events on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).